# Arguments from Visual Basic to Batch File

Tags: vba, batch-file

I know this is easy. I am an administrator, not a FT programmer. I am trying to pass the prjFilename and emailFilename arguments to a Batch file. To ensure the values are correct, I am popping a MsgBox in the Else branch. Everything is fine there. The problem is that when I attempt to use the variable in the Batch file, that variable string is cut off at the very first space in the filename path.

So when I echo %1% to test it, I get a truncated path. Any help is appreciated.

```
    If prjFilename = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select a GSA Project File to process")

    ElseIf emailFilename = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select a list of emails to process")

    Else
        Dim DosRun As Process = New Process
        Dim strArgs As String
        MsgBox(prjFilename)
        MsgBox(emailFilename)
        strArgs = prjFilename & " " & emailFilename
        MsgBox(strArgs)
        DosRun.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
        DosRun.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\KRUSH\krush.cmd"
        DosRun.StartInfo.Arguments = prjFilename & " " & emailFilename
        DosRun.Start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either of `prjFilename` or `emailFilename` contain spaces, then you need to place double quotation characters around them when passing them to the batch file. A double quotation character literal in VBA is `""""` (I kid you not).

```
strArgs = """" & prjFilename & """" & " " & """" & emailFilename & """"
```

I normally define `Public Const vbQuote as String = """"` at the top of a module and use that.